# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.models.User

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a user table structured this way

```
id    name     email
1     cc       cc@yahoo.com
2     rr       rr@yahoo.com
3     cc       cc@yahoo.com
```

I am writing a query to save a log when ever it finds an email matching any of the row with the below hql

```
String hql = "FROM User c WHERE c.email = :email order by c.id";
        return (User) _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("email", email);
```

When I run my code I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.models.User
    at com.models.UserDao.getByEmail(UserDao.java:62)
```

Comment: Do you expect one result? Or more than one?

Comment: more than one result

Comment: It seems that you are missing the `.getResultList()` at the end of your command.

Comment: @Francis so it makes no sense to cast it to a User object since the result will provide you with something else, you need to get the first result and then cast it to a user.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call [`uniqueResult()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult()) to get the first result, the code should rather be:

```
 return (User) _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
    .setParameter("email", email)
    .uniqueResult();
```

Indeed you get this error because you try to cast a `Query` instance into a `User` which cannot be done, you need to execute the query first to get your `User` instance.

---

If you want to get several results then consider using [`list()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()), the code will then be something like:

```
 return (List<User>) _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
    .setParameter("email", email)
    .list();
```

Comment: what about if i want to get the third row

Comment: Yeah, that's why i asked if he needed one or more than one result. @NicolasFilotto

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to call the `getResultList()` method at the end.

```
return (List<User>) _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
              .setParameter("email", email)
              .getResultList();
```

You should notice that since you are expecting more than one result, you'll need to change this command a bit or adapt the code to where this is returning to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract your result out of Query. You can extract a single Object by using

```
.createQuery(hql).getSingleResult();
```